# grant select on all databases except one mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, permissions

I have user called `test_user` created under `MySQL 5.5.17` under MS Windows 2008R2, I want to grant this user select privileges on all databases except MySQL database, note I have around 200 database inside this instance.

EDIT:

[image]

EDIT2:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the output of the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT("GRANT SELECT ON ",SCHEMA_NAME,".* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';")
FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT LIKE 'mysql';
```

Comment: thanks I did not think about this solution (upvote)

Comment: Note that this is not "future proof": `GRANT ... ON 'xx_%'` grants privileges from all DB names like `xx_%` even the ones that do not exist yet, while this `SELECT ...` query must be run after every DB creation on the server

Answer (score 5):

Since you have 200 databases and you do not want to grant one by one. Fastest way to do that would be

```
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then just revoke the privilege in mysql db

```
REVOKE SELECT ON mysql.* FROM 'test_user'@'localhost' ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But when I selectively GRANT and then REVOKE on mysql.* . Then it is working

[image]

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 150
Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE USER 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mysqlrockstar@localhost                |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost' |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON mysql.* TO 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u mysqlrockstar
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 151
Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 152
Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> REVOKE SELECT  ON mysql.* FROM 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit;
Bye
user@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u mysqlrockstar
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 153
Server version: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mysqlrockstar'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
```

Comment: I tried this but I found this error message as in the screenshot in the edit section.

Comment: Check `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test_user'@'aabuhasna-pc' ;`

Comment: I added the result of the command in edit2 section

Comment: On doing GRANT and then REVOKE  explicitly for mysql.* It is working

Comment: Not good enough -- That only removes the entry from `mysql.db`.  The entry in `mysql.user` still lets the user have access.  (Downvote)

Comment: You are completely wrong. On doing that the user will not see the mysql database at all if issues `SHOW DATABASES`. I can prove that by giving screen shot

Comment: Please demo by connecting and doing a `SELECT`.

Comment: @Rick James Check the demo now

Comment: With MySQL 5.7.19 I get error `ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'myuser' on host '%'` when I attempt `REVOKE SELECT  ON mysql.* FROM 'myuser'@'%'`

Comment: You can't revoke grants on a specific database when you have granted them to the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Years later and in MariaDB. What I do:

- grant access to all databases
- grant only 'LOCK TABLES' on mysql.*

User can see mysql, but no tables. Lock table does not work, because te user cannot access any tables.